# How can I get the text from this specific div class?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the text here

a lot of text

I used

```
url = ('https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1521445')
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    mestuff = soup.find("div", {"class":"bbcode bbcode--profile-page"})
```

but it never fails to return with "None" in the terminal.

How can I go about this?

Link is "https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1521445"

(This is a repost since the old question was super old. I don't know if I should've made another question or not but aa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is dynamically loaded from script tag so, as in other answer, you can grab from that tag. You can target the tag by its id then you need to pull out the relevant json, then the html from that json, then parse html which would have been loaded dynamically on page (at this point you can use your original class selector)

```
import requests, json, pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1521445')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
all_data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#json-user').text)
soup = bs(all_data['page']['html'], 'lxml')
pprint.pprint(soup.select_one('.bbcode--profile-page').get_text('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
url = ('https://osu.ppy.sh/users/1521445')
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
x = soup.findAll("script",{"id":re.compile(r"json-user")})
result = re.findall('raw\":(.+)},\"previous_usernames', x[0].text.strip())
print(result)
```

Im not sure why the `div` with `class='bbcode bbcode--profile-page'` is `string` inside `script` tag with `class='json-user'`, that's why you can't get it's value by `div` with `class='bbcode bbcode--profile-page'`

Hope this could help

[image]